# Win IoT SnapDragon downloading files from SD Card via Ftp possible?

Tags: download, ftp, sd-card, windows-10-iot-core, qualcomm

This concerns Win IoT on Qualcomm's Snapdragon where the OS does not reside on the SD card but on the board itself. We can use Ftp to access files that are stored onboard but we cannot ftp directly to the external SD card. We create a large number of log files on the external SD card and we need to download such files via Ftp. Is this possible and how?

Comment: To clarify, you want the device to perform the download of FTP files and copy them to an SD card also attached to the device? What have you tried so far? My first thoughts are that this should be fairly easy to do in PowerShell.

Comment: Clarification: The Snapdragon device  is connected via WiFi to a computer,. Log files are generated by the device and stored on its attatche SD card. Snapdragon differs from the Raspberry in that they keep the IoT OS on internal storage media. The internal drive is visible to ftp but the external SD card is not. The challenge is to download (ftp) files from the external SD card to the PC over WiFi. Thanks for your help!